# excel vba user type not defined after removing class module

Tags: vba, excel

I have an Excel VBA Project which included a custom class module. I changed the code to remove all references to this class, then removed the class module after exporting it. The program then had a compile error

> user type not defined

I re-imported the custom class and the program compiled normally. I deleted all code and comments from the custom class module, leaving it as a blank module, and the program still compiled OK. Again, after removing the custom class I get the "user type not defined" error. 
No offending code line is highlighted at any of the above steps.
Any ideas?

Comment: Seems like it is being referenced somewhere in your code.

Comment: Somewhere you declared a variable as that class. Search for the class name in the project.

Comment: Are you requiring all variables to be declared?  Is `Option Explicit` at the beginning of your regular module?  If it is, it may help to find the problem, although it should highlight even without that.

Comment: Every module uses Option Explicit. I deleted all references to the class and cleared the contents of the class module, even changed the module name, and it still compiled correctly. So it is a mystery why it will not compile when I remove the class module from the project.
I guess I can just leave it there, perhaps use it for some other code, but that concerns me there may be a deeper problem.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was experienced using Excel 2016.
The problem was solved by opening the file in Excel 2007, which I fortunately retained before installing Office 365. In Excel 2007 I was able to remove the now empty class module and re-compile and save. On re-opening in Excel 2016, the project again compiled just fine.
I repeated the process on another backup copy with both Excel 2007 and 2016 and the problem consistently occurs with Excel 2016 but not with Excel 2007.
Thanks for other's comments.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with the same message "user type not defined" running Excel 2007.

The problem arose when I was updating the code in a class module and removed an old private user-defined type and all references to it. This then raised the compiler error "user type not defined".

My temporary solution was (for this description let the type name be "TName"):

1. Remove "TName" and all references to it from the class module.
2. Create a new empty class module and name it "TName".
3. Recompiled and save the project.
4. Remove the newly created class module "TName".
5. Recompiled and save the project.
6. Exit all instances of Excel.
7. Restart excel with the project.
8. Done.

Note!
This removes the compiler error "user type not defined" for the moment. However, if any other error appears and it has not even have to be related to the "user type not defined" issue. The error "user type not defined" reappears. So, this is a description to remove the error for the moment. But if further development is done, it is most likely that the error will reappear and if it is not documented thoroughly it will be even harder to fix, since then you probably have forgotten the type name that originally caused the error!

This is a rough description of what I have done. However, I thought I would contribute my work here and let the next person come up with a better solution and description.